# C#.Net Getting Last day of the Previous Month from current date

Tags: c#, .net

A quick expression anyone please?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;    
var firstDayCurrentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

var lastDayLastMonth = firstDayCurrentMonth.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Excellent! just done a unit test for this and works for both leap and non leap year!

Comment: It also works when current month is January, it returns the last date of last month of last year.

Answer (score 17):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime lastDayOfLastMonth = now.Date.AddDays(-now.Day);
```

Comment: Multiple DateTime.Now calls can be costly, as a new instance of the DateTime struct is created every time it's referenced.

Comment: @opedog: Costly is a relative term. This *slow* version can manage about 1.7M iterations/second on my machine, compared to about 2.7M iterations/second if I call `DateTime.Now` once and re-use the instance. Certainly a decent improvement, but I doubt if it would be noticed in most real-world situations.

Comment: The problem isn't that the code is *costly*. The problem is that the code is *wrong* because it has a *race condition*. What if the code runs such that the first call to Now happens at 23:59:59.9999 on Nov 30th, and the second call to Now happens at 12:00:00.0001 on December 1st?  Race conditions aren't just a problem in threading situations; they're a problem in any situation in which exact details of timing matter.

Comment: @Eric: Good point, kicking myself for not spotting that one! Edited accordingly - now it's faster *and* correct!

Answer (score 4):

Try the [DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)

Here's an example:

```
DateTime oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(oneMonthAgo.Year, oneMonthAgo.Month);
```

Comment: @tomfanning... pardon? How is it MORE ingenious to NOT use the function that is meant to do exactly what you want?

Comment: So the quality of an answer can only be evaluated when compared to others?

Comment: I prefer the elegance of the "work out first day of this month, take a day off" approach where you don't ever have to take account of the exceptional case (January).